# Executing MySQL Queries using Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm attempting to run some MySQL queries and output the results in my Python program. I've created this function that is called and the cursor is passed through. However, I am running into a problem where running the below code will always return `None` / nothing.

Here is what I have:

```
def showInformation(cursor):
    number_rows = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "DB"'
    testing = cursor.execute(number_rows)

    print(testing)
```

When using the `cursor` object itself, I do not run into any problems:

```
for row in cursor:
         print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need:

```
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

because you are returning only a count and so you expect one row.

Calling `execute` is not supposed to return anything unless `multi=True` is specified according to [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). The programmer can only iterate the `cursor`  like you did, or call `fetchone` to retrieve one row or call `fetchall` to retrieve all rows or call `fetchmany` to retrieve some rows.